# run-time error - 2147217900 80040e14

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to execute a VBA Query in my Excel file.

From my Excel file, I can select any other excel file using ADODB connection. 
It then extracts the headers and unique values of each header from the of  the target file. 
Then, user can select the required headers and criteria to create a new table in my Excel in a new sheet.

All my code works fine. But , when the Query contains large number of data or criteria, it shows this error.

For E.g.:, User chose columns 1 and 2 to be displayed as results where column data can be serial numbers from 1 to 1000 and column 2 data is a specific text ('say, PROCESS COMPLETED'). When the serial numbers are from 1 to 1000 , it displays this error. But , if the number of serial numbers are less, the code works fine.

An Example Query : SELECT [S/N],[Process or Metrology] FROM[MIMO Masterfile$] WHERE (([S/N]=1 OR [S/N]=2 OR [S/N]=3 OR [S/N]=4 OR [S/N]=5 OR [S/N]=6 OR [S/N]=7 OR [S/N]=8 OR [S/N]=9 OR [S/N]=10 OR [S/N]=11 OR [S/N]=12 OR [S/N]=13 OR [S/N]=14 OR [S/N]=15 OR [S/N]=16 OR [S/N]=17 OR [S/N]=18 OR [S/N]=19 OR [S/N]=20 OR [S/N]=21 OR [S/N]=22 OR [S/N]=23 OR [S/N]=24 OR [S/N]=25 OR [S/N]=26 OR [S/N]=27 OR [S/N]=28 OR [S/N]=29 OR [S/N]=30 OR [S/N]=31 OR [S/N]=32 OR [S/N]=33 OR [S/N]=34 OR [S/N]=35 OR [S/N]=36 OR [S/N]=37 OR [S/N]=38 OR [S/N]=39 OR [S/N]=40 OR [S/N]=41 OR [S/N]=42 OR [S/N]=43 OR [S/N]=44 OR [S/N]=45 OR [S/N]=46 OR [S/N]=47 OR [S/N]=48 OR [S/N]=49 OR [S/N]=50 OR [S/N]=51 OR [S/N]=52 OR [S/N]=53 OR [S/N]=54 OR [S/N]=55 OR [S/N]=56 OR [S/N]=57 OR [S/N]=58 OR [S/N]=59 OR [S/N]=60 OR [S/N]=61 OR [S/N]=62 OR [S/N]=63 OR [S/N]=64 OR [S/N]=65 OR [S/N]=66 OR [S/N]=67 OR [S/N]=68 OR [S/N]=69 OR [S/N]=70 OR [S/N]=71 OR [S/N]=72 OR [S/N]=73 OR [S/N]=74 OR [S/N]=75 OR [S/N]=76 OR [S/N]=77 OR [S/N]=78 OR [S/N]=79 OR [S/N]=80 OR [S/N]=81 OR [S/N]=82 OR [S/N]=83 OR [S/N]=84 OR [S/N]=85 OR [S/N]=86 OR [S/N]=87 OR [S/N]=88 OR [S/N]=89 OR [S/N]=90 OR [S/N]=91 OR [S/N]=92 OR [S/N]=93 OR [S/N]=94 OR [S/N]=95 OR [S/N]=96 OR [S/N]=97 OR [S/N]=98 OR [S/N]=99 OR [S/N]=100 OR [S/N]=101 OR [S/N]=102 OR [S/N]=103 OR [S/N]=104 OR [S/N]=105 OR [S/N]=106 OR [S/N]=107 OR [S/N]=108 OR [S/N]=109 OR [S/N]=110 OR [S/N]=111 OR [S/N]=112 OR [S/N]=113 OR [S/N]=114 OR [S/N]=115 OR [S/N]=116 OR [S/N]=117 OR [S/N]=118 OR [S/N]=119 OR [S/N]=120 OR [S/N]=121 OR [S/N]=122 OR [S/N]=123 OR [S/N]=124 OR [S/N]=125 OR [S/N]=126 OR [S/N]=127 OR [S/N]=128 OR [S/N]=129 OR [S/N]=130 OR [S/N]=131 OR [S/N]=132 OR [S/N]=133 OR [S/N]=134 OR [S/N]=135 OR [S/N]=136 OR [S/N]=137 OR [S/N]=138 OR [S/N]=139 OR [S/N]=140 OR [S/N]=141 OR [S/N]=142 OR [S/N]=143 OR [S/N]=144 OR [S/N]=145 OR [S/N]=146 OR [S/N]=147 OR [S/N]=148 OR [S/N]=149 OR [S/N]=150 OR [S/N]=151 OR [S/N]=152 OR [S/N]=153 OR [S/N]=154 OR [S/N]=155 OR [S/N]=156 OR [S/N]=157 OR [S/N]=158 OR [S/N]=159 OR [S/N]=160 OR [S/N]=161 OR [S/N]=162 OR [S/N]=163 OR [S/N]=164 OR [S/N]=165 OR [S/N]=166 OR [S/N]=167 OR [S/N]=168 OR [S/N]=169 OR [S/N]=170 OR [S/N]=171 OR [S/N]=172 OR [S/N]=173 OR [S/N]=174 OR [S/N]=175 OR [S/N]=176 OR [S/N]=177 OR [S/N]=178 OR [S/N]=179 OR [S/N]=180 OR [S/N]=181 OR [S/N]=182 OR [S/N]=183 OR [S/N]=184 OR [S/N]=185 OR [S/N]=186 OR [S/N]=187 OR [S/N]=188 OR [S/N]=189 OR [S/N]=190 OR [S/N]=191 OR [S/N]=192 OR [S/N]=193 OR [S/N]=194 OR [S/N]=195 OR [S/N]=196 OR [S/N]=197 OR [S/N]=198 OR [S/N]=199 OR [S/N]=200 OR [S/N]=201 OR [S/N]=202 OR [S/N]=203 OR [S/N]=204 OR [S/N]=205 OR [S/N]=206 OR [S/N]=207 OR [S/N]=208 OR [S/N]=209 OR [S/N]=210 OR [S/N]=211 OR [S/N]=212 OR [S/N]=213 OR [S/N]=214 OR [S/N]=215 OR [S/N]=216 OR [S/N]=217 OR [S/N]=218 OR [S/N]=219 OR [S/N]=220 OR [S/N]=221 OR [S/N]=222 OR [S/N]=223 OR [S/N]=224 OR [S/N]=225 OR [S/N]=226 OR [S/N]=227 OR [S/N]=228 OR [S/N]=229 OR [S/N]=230 OR [S/N]=231 OR [S/N]=232 OR [S/N]=233 OR [S/N]=234 OR [S/N]=235 OR [S/N]=236 OR [S/N]=237 OR [S/N]=238 OR [S/N]=239 OR [S/N]=240 OR [S/N]=241 OR [S/N]=242 OR [S/N]=243 OR [S/N]=244 OR [S/N]=245 OR [S/N]=246 OR [S/N]=247 OR [S/N]=248 OR [S/N]=249 OR [S/N]=250 OR [S/N]=251 OR [S/N]=252 OR [S/N]=253 OR [S/N]=254 OR [S/N]=255 OR [S/N]=256 OR [S/N]=257 OR [S/N]=258 OR [S/N]=259 OR [S/N]=260 OR [S/N]=261 OR [S/N]=262 OR [S/N]=263 OR [S/N]=264 OR [S/N]=265 OR [S/N]=266 OR [S/N]=267 OR [S/N]=268 OR [S/N]=269 OR [S/N]=270 OR [S/N]=271 OR [S/N]=272 OR [S/N]=273 OR [S/N]=274 OR [S/N]=275 OR [S/N]=276 OR [S/N]=277 OR [S/N]=278 OR [S/N]=279 OR [S/N]=280 OR [S/N]=281 OR [S/N]=282 OR [S/N]=283 OR [S/N]=284 OR [S/N]=285 OR [S/N]=286 OR [S/N]=287 OR [S/N]=288 OR [S/N]=289 OR [S/N]=290 OR [S/N]=291 OR [S/N]=292 OR [S/N]=293 OR [S/N]=294 OR [S/N]=295 OR [S/N]=296 OR [S/N]=297 OR [S/N]=298 OR [S/N]=299 OR [S/N]=300 OR [S/N]=301 OR [S/N]=302 OR [S/N]=303 OR [S/N]=304 OR [S/N]=305 OR [S/N]=306 OR [S/N]=307 OR [S/N]=308 OR [S/N]=309 OR [S/N]=310 OR [S/N]=311 OR [S/N]=312 OR [S/N]=313 OR [S/N]=314 OR [S/N]=315 OR [S/N]=316 OR [S/N]=317 OR [S/N]=318 OR [S/N]=319 OR [S/N]=320 OR [S/N]=321 OR [S/N]=322 OR [S/N]=323 OR [S/N]=324 OR [S/N]=325 OR [S/N]=326 OR [S/N]=327 OR [S/N]=328 OR [S/N]=329 OR [S/N]=330 OR [S/N]=331 OR [S/N]=332 OR [S/N]=333 OR [S/N]=334 OR [S/N]=335 OR [S/N]=336 OR [S/N]=337 OR [S/N]=338 OR [S/N]=339 OR [S/N]=340 OR [S/N]=341 OR [S/N]=342 OR [S/N]=343 OR [S/N]=344 OR [S/N]=345 OR [S/N]=346 OR [S/N]=347 OR [S/N]=348 OR [S/N]=349 OR [S/N]=350 OR [S/N]=351 OR [S/N]=352 OR [S/N]=353 OR [S/N]=354 OR [S/N]=355 OR [S/N]=356 OR [S/N]=357 OR [S/N]=358 OR [S/N]=359 OR [S/N]=360 OR [S/N]=361 OR [S/N]=362 OR [S/N]=363 OR [S/N]=364 OR [S/N]=365 OR [S/N]=366 OR [S/N]=367 OR [S/N]=368 OR [S/N]=369 OR [S/N]=370 OR [S/N]=371 OR [S/N]=372 OR [S/N]=373 OR [S/N]=374 OR [S/N]=375 OR [S/N]=376 OR [S/N]=377 OR [S/N]=378 OR [S/N]=379 OR [S/N]=380 OR [S/N]=381 OR [S/N]=382 OR [S/N]=383 OR [S/N]=384 OR [S/N]=385 OR [S/N]=386 OR [S/N]=387 OR [S/N]=388 OR [S/N]=389 OR [S/N]=390 OR [S/N]=391 OR [S/N]=392 OR [S/N]=393 OR [S/N]=394 OR [S/N]=395 OR [S/N]=396 OR [S/N]=397 OR [S/N]=398 OR [S/N]=399 OR [S/N]=400 OR [S/N]=401 OR [S/N]=402 OR [S/N]=403 OR [S/N]=404 OR [S/N]=405 OR [S/N]=406 OR [S/N]=407 OR [S/N]=408 OR [S/N]=409 OR [S/N]=410 OR [S/N]=411 OR [S/N]=412 OR [S/N]=413 OR [S/N]=414 OR [S/N]=415 OR [S/N]=416 OR [S/N]=417 OR [S/N]=418 OR [S/N]=419 OR [S/N]=420 OR [S/N]=421 OR [S/N]=422 OR [S/N]=423 OR [S/N]=424 OR [S/N]=425 OR [S/N]=426 OR [S/N]=427 OR [S/N]=428 OR [S/N]=429 OR [S/N]=430 OR [S/N]=431 OR [S/N]=432 OR [S/N]=433 OR [S/N]=434 OR [S/N]=435 OR [S/N]=436 OR [S/N]=437 OR [S/N]=438 OR [S/N]=439 OR [S/N]=440 OR [S/N]=441 OR [S/N]=442 OR [S/N]=443 OR [S/N]=444 OR [S/N]=445 OR [S/N]=446 OR [S/N]=447 OR [S/N]=448 OR [S/N]=449 OR [S/N]=450 OR [S/N]=451 OR [S/N]=452 OR [S/N]=453 OR [S/N]=454 OR [S/N]=455 OR [S/N]=456 OR [S/N]=457 OR [S/N]=458 OR [S/N]=459 OR [S/N]=460 OR [S/N]=461 OR [S/N]=462 OR [S/N]=463 OR [S/N]=464 OR [S/N]=465 OR [S/N]=466 OR [S/N]=467 OR [S/N]=468 OR [S/N]=469 OR [S/N]=470 OR [S/N]=471 OR [S/N]=472 OR [S/N]=473 OR [S/N]=474 OR [S/N]=475 OR [S/N]=476 OR [S/N]=477 OR [S/N]=478 OR [S/N]=479 OR [S/N]=480 OR [S/N]=481 OR [S/N]=482 OR [S/N]=483 OR [S/N]=484 OR [S/N]=485 OR [S/N]=486 OR [S/N]=487 OR [S/N]=488 OR [S/N]=489 OR [S/N]=490 OR [S/N]=491 OR [S/N]=492 OR [S/N]=493 OR [S/N]=494 OR [S/N]=495 OR [S/N]=496 OR [S/N]=497 OR [S/N]=498 OR [S/N]=499 OR [S/N]=500 OR [S/N]=501 OR [S/N]=502 OR [S/N]=503 OR [S/N]=504 OR [S/N]=505 OR [S/N]=506 OR [S/N]=507 OR [S/N]=508 OR [S/N]=509 OR [S/N]=510 OR [S/N]=511 OR [S/N]=512 OR [S/N]=513 OR [S/N]=514 OR [S/N]=515 OR [S/N]=516 OR [S/N]=517 OR [S/N]=518 OR [S/N]=519 OR [S/N]=520 OR [S/N]=521 OR [S/N]=522 OR [S/N]=523 OR [S/N]=524 OR [S/N]=525 OR [S/N]=526 OR [S/N]=527 OR [S/N]=528 OR [S/N]=529 OR [S/N]=530 OR [S/N]=531 OR [S/N]=532 OR [S/N]=533 OR [S/N]=534 OR [S/N]=535 OR [S/N]=536 OR [S/N]=537 OR [S/N]=538 OR [S/N]=539 OR [S/N]=540 OR [S/N]=541 OR [S/N]=542 OR [S/N]=543 OR [S/N]=544 OR [S/N]=545 OR [S/N]=546 OR [S/N]=547 OR [S/N]=548 OR [S/N]=549 OR [S/N]=550 OR [S/N]=551 OR [S/N]=552 OR [S/N]=553 OR [S/N]=554 OR [S/N]=555 OR [S/N]=556 OR [S/N]=557 OR [S/N]=558 OR [S/N]=559 OR [S/N]=560 OR [S/N]=561 OR [S/N]=562 OR [S/N]=563 OR [S/N]=564 OR [S/N]=565 OR [S/N]=566 OR [S/N]=567 OR [S/N]=568 OR [S/N]=569 OR [S/N]=570 OR [S/N]=571 OR [S/N]=572 OR [S/N]=573 OR [S/N]=574 OR [S/N]=575 OR [S/N]=576 OR [S/N]=577 OR [S/N]=578 OR [S/N]=579 OR [S/N]=580 OR [S/N]=581 OR [S/N]=582 OR [S/N]=583 OR [S/N]=584 OR [S/N]=585 OR [S/N]=586 OR [S/N]=587 OR [S/N]=588 OR [S/N]=589 OR [S/N]=590 OR [S/N]=591 OR [S/N]=592 OR [S/N]=593 OR [S/N]=594 OR [S/N]=595 OR [S/N]=596 OR [S/N]=597 OR [S/N]=598 OR [S/N]=599 OR [S/N]=600 OR [S/N]=601 OR [S/N]=602 OR [S/N]=603 OR [S/N]=604 OR [S/N]=605 OR [S/N]=606 OR [S/N]=607 OR [S/N]=608 OR [S/N]=609 OR [S/N]=610 OR [S/N]=611 OR [S/N]=612 OR [S/N]=613 OR [S/N]=614 OR [S/N]=615 OR [S/N]=616 OR [S/N]=617 OR [S/N]=618 OR [S/N]=619) AND ([Process or Metrology]='Process'))

This query automatically forms depending on user's choices from a listbox. 
Please do help me to sort out the error.

Comment: Is it not possible to use IN or a JOIN to a table holding the S/N? The above looks mildly insane.

Comment: @Fionnuala I am completely new to Visual Basic. !!  So I am not sure about it's use. Can u pls explain how to use IN or JOIN for this kinda queries..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to run large queries via recordset and not like sheet query table.
To understand the IN operator see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

This is example how you can build and run your query:

```
Sub BuildAndRun_Sane_Query()

' Create IN_string:
Dim SN, S_In As String, s_query  As String
For Each SN In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) ' Define your input range
    S_In = S_In & IIf(S_In = "", "", ",") & "'" & SN & "'"
Next
S_In = "(" & S_In & ")"

s_query = "SELECT [S/N],[Process or Metrology] FROM [MIMO Masterfile$] WHERE [S/N] IN " & S_In
s_conn = "ODBC;DSN=AnyODBCName" ' Define your connection string

'Execute the query on sheet "Output"
Query_via_Recordset Sheets("Output"), s_query, s_conn

End Sub
```

To see what connection string is used in the excel workbook go to tab Data, button Connections, Open the connection properties and in definition you will see the Connection string.

```
Sub Query_via_Recordset(sh As Worksheet, s_cmd As String, s_conn As String)
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset, s_Header As String, l_col As Long
sh.Cells.ClearContents
rst.Open s_cmd, s_conn
'Query headers:
l_col = 1
For Each s_Header In rst.Fields
    sh.Cells(1, l_col) = v_ariant.Name
    l_col = l_col + 1
Next
'Query Data:
sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
End Sub
```